# PhoneGap - Ripple - Google Maps: Drag Issue

Tags: cordova, maps, typeerror, ripple

I'm messing around with the google maps API and I'm trying to get their interactive map working via PhoneGap, which I am then emulating via Ripple.

I've literally copied this tutorial:

http://www.christianengvall.se/phonegap-and-google-maps/

And when I open it within Ripple, it all loads fine, but every time I click and drag the map, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'item'
    Jq.(anonymous function).$a
    (anonymous function)
    _simulateTouchEvent
    _translateMouseEvent
```

My guess is that it's coming from the ripple emulator. Is there a fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I'm getting the same issue...

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to open Chrome's Developer tools, and on the bottom right corner is a "gear" icon.
Click this.  The settings window will come up and then the second option on the left is "overrides".  Click this.  Towards the bottom, you'll see a checkbox that's labeled "Emulate Touch Events".  Check this and the dragging features work, but you'll still get the occasional error as you mentioned.